# amplify.js and backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, amplifyjs

recently i had a chance to watch beautiful course from john papa on building single page application. i' d love it.  it touches every aspect of application both server and client side.

i was more into client side. during his implementation mr.papa had similar structure in clientside. such as data services, mocking, data caching and offline features it  was impressive. one of libraries that frequently was mentioned is amplify.js

since in his work mr.papa has referred to knockout, as someone who has started digging and working in backbone.js. want to find out does similar structure would be applicable for backbone. or more precisely could backbone also benefited from amplify.js or it s already built in underhood of backbone.async method?

ref:jonhpapa.net

Comment: please edit your question it is confusing on what is required by you. Are you asking if amplify.js is required with backbone.js ? or How to structure a backbone.js application ?

Comment: actually i was referring both, does similar data services come out of box in backbone or should we implement ourselves if so is amplify.js i s right tool? i scoured stackoverflow and could not find similar posting. obviously amplify.js has less role in backbone world. however would like to hear it, make it explicit.

Answer (score 3):

> could backbone also benefited from amplify.js

Yes, but you'd have to override [Backbone.Sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) in order to use the client-side persistence provided by the [Amplify.js Store API](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/).

[Backbone.amplify](https://github.com/dev360/Backbone.amplify) looks promising, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: thanks. but how come nobody has gone this route.  i could not find any reference for backbone client-side persistence via amplify or any other libs.